# PHP doesn't see the request sent by REACT

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm trying to send a POST request from react to PHP and this is my code:

```
function getPhp(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log(xhr.responseText)
    })

    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/anima/index.php')

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ dt: 'data' }))
}
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
if (isset($_POST['dt'])) {
  echo $_POST['dt'];
}
```

However, the only response I get is

```
Array
(
)
```

Due to the $_REQUEST. I checked the network in the dev tools and[image] everything seems fine.

Comment: Doesn't `XMLHttpRequest.send()` need an URL query string (`dt=data` in your case), as opposed to JSON?

Comment: @Jeto I tried that too, it didn't work. Plus if that was the case, would ```$_REQUEST``` show something?

Comment: You should check the `Params` tab on the browser's console, instead of `Headers`. Does it show something?

Comment: Also, according to the docs, you need to add this: 
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` if you're passing url-encoded data. This might just be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest.

Comment: @Jeto yep thats right. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jeto u finna add it as answer or?

Comment: Not worth it, I think I'll just mark it as a duplicate of the other one (edit: well scratch that, I messed up).